# Bulk downloading PDF files in iPad

Tags: pdf, data-transfer, ipad

I'd like to know whether there is an app or a service which allows bulk downloading of PDF files from a site page. More generally, is there an app that allows bulk downloading to iPad given a string pattern, like the file name or the file extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## curl

You can use a `curl` client for iPhone/iPad to do this (e.g. [iCurl](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icurl/id480568361) or [iCurlHTTP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icurlhttp/id611943891)). Than you can use this client to download multiple files like this:

```
curl -L -O http://www.example.com/file[1-5].pdf
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this method (first, I must learn something more about cUrl and the way it works).